# xcrun Error running program with custom malloc on macOS

Tags: c, macos, malloc, clang, free

I am writing a custom `malloc()` - `free()` - `realloc()` set of functions for a school project.

I've written such functions and they appear to work, for example I can launch a simple program with my custom malloc and everithing works fine.

My malloc library is compiled as such (`gcc` is symlinked to `clang`):

```
# gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -shared -o libft_malloc_x86_64_Darwin.so ./src/malloc.o ./src/free.o ./src/realloc.o ./src/find.o ./src/alloc_mem.o ./src/show_alloc_mem.o ./src/utils.o -I ./include -I ./libft/include -I ./libft/libft -L./libft/ -L. -lft
```

Now, I tried to launch `lldb` with my malloc like this:

```
# ./run.sh lldb
```

with `./run.sh` being:

```
#!/bin/sh
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=.;
export DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="libft_malloc.so";
export DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1;
$@;
```

And I've got this error:

```
xcrun: error: unable to resolve xcrun_main (invalid handle passed to dlsym()).
```

What is this error about? I suppose this is a linker problem, but what this means exactly?

I've searched some info around, but nothing yet. 
Any tip is appreciated, as I will dig it.

I'm using macOS 10.12.6 and

```
# gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: It looks like the `xcrun` program tried to `dlopen()` a shared library at runtime, but failed.  This might result from you clobbering whatever is ordinarily in `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`; if that variable is non-empty when your `run.sh` script gets its hands on it then you should probably keep its contents and append (or prepend) any extra directories you want.  Remember that the path list in that variable is analogous to the executable `PATH`: a colon-separated list of directory names.

Answer (score 0):

this error could happen when a function called from dynamic library does not exist. So, when you make export these variables, libc malloc will be replaced with yours. Do you implement all functions from this library?